# Copy numbers from SAP to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I tried to copy numbers from a SAP table to Excel through a SAP script.
The current format of the numbers is 1.650,00, but when the SAP script pastes it to Excel the result in Excel is 2.

I realize that in Excel the system reads the dots (1000 separator) as comma for decimal.

How can I copy the numbers as they are in SAP?

```
Set xclapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  
'Set objExcel = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FBL5N")
objsheet.Select
objsheet.Range("A1").Select
objsheet.Paste
```

Comment: [Change the separators](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e).

Comment: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/52122/excel-2013-convert-european-numbers-to-american/

Comment: instead of select and then paste your should just say "objsheet.Cells(1,1).Value = "your value"

Comment: The problem relates to localization settings of your machine. Visit the control panel -> Region and Language -> Formats Tab -> Additional Settings button -> Numbers tab. There you will see the format of numbers your machine understands is different from the format excel reads. Excel is reading as per the regional settings. So change the settings accordingly.